# rod cutting problems in recursive method. Why dose ` p[i]+ rodCutting(n-i) ` works?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

When I learn the dp,the first example I encountered was rod cutting problem with its not smart method.
I just confused with the steps when cut the original rod into two pieces, it just get the maximum with `p[i]+ rodCutting(n-i)`.But I think it should be `rodCutting(i)+rodCutting(n-i)`.How dose it works? Why dose `p[i]+ rodCutting(n-i)` works?

```
static int[] priceList = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};//the list about the price of each inches
    /**
     * use recursive
     * priceList
     * length：0 < length
     * @return
     */
    public static int rodCuttingL(int length){
        if(length <= 0) return 0;
        //when given length greater than priceList.length
        if(length > priceList.length){
            int n = (length)/(priceList.length);
            int r = length%(priceList.length);
            System.out.println("n = " + r);
            return n * rodCuttingL(priceList.length) + rodCuttingL(r);
        }
        int price = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int i = 1;
        for(; i <= length; i++){
            price = max(price,priceList[i-1],rodCuttingL(i) + rodCuttingL(length - i));

        }

        return price;
    }
```

I hope someone can solve my confusion, thanks!

Comment: *"I just confused"* is not a clear problem statement. The algorithm is explained at numerous places, like [here](https://www.codesdope.com/course/algorithms-rod-cutting/), [here](https://faculty.unist.ac.kr/algo/wp-content/uploads/sites/362/2021/07/cse331lec18.pdf), and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/rod-cutting-problem), ....